# How do I configure grafana to use Oauth2 when it's behind an Application Load Balancer?

Tags: oauth, grafana

I am trying to configure Google Oauth2 for a grafana instance.

My grafana runs in a Amazon EC2 instance which is behind an ALB. The ALB is using SSL, but not the grafana instance.

I setup Oauth2 on Grafana and I can see the "Login using google" button.
However, when I press it and choose my google account, I am getting the following error:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
http://grafana.acme-live.co.uk:3000/login/google
```

The configuration on the google side is straight forward, I entered my
"authorized javascript origins":

```
https://grafana.acme-live.co.uk
```

and the "authorised redirect URL":

```
https://grafana.acme-live.co.uk:3000/login/google
```

my grafana.ini file:

```
protocol = http
http_port = 3000
domain = grafana.acme-live.co.uk
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/
enabled = true
client_id = acme.apps.googleusercontent.com
client_secret = acme-ACME
scopes = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
auth_url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
token_url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
allowed_domains = grafana.acme-live.co.uk
allow_sign_up = true
```

It seems to me that GoogleOauth is confused because it's expecting a auth request via SSL but the grafana server sends a request in plain HTTP.

After the AUTH process, Google tries to contact the grafana server back on port 3000, but it's hitting the LB on that port and the LB does not listen on that port :

https://grafana.acme-live.co.uk:3000/login/google?state=XXYCuMtOvhap1B8urTCCOiXXYCurL8LRXL2yIVDcYUE%3D&code=4/0AX4XfWhGzhjj3JygxB2kMzxa8NMtOvhap1B8QrHhMQQx9ev032k5ChwEJINnbaM94ykRCA&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20openid&authuser=0&hd=acme.com&prompt=consent

How do I configure grafana to use Oauth2 when it's behind an Application Load Balancer ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/google/

> You may have to set the root_url option of [server] for the callback URL to be correct. For example in case you are serving Grafana behind a proxy.

That's your problem. So try (I guess you want to expose it on `http://grafana.acme-live.co.uk`, not on the port 3000):

```
[server]
root_url = https://grafana.acme.co.uk/
```

"authorised redirect URL" in the Google client config:

```
https://grafana.acme-live.co.uk/login/google
```

Comment: so, I replaced root_url by typing it in plain text instead of using variable names defined in the grafana.ini file, and made some progress but I was stuck with another error message. 
I googled it and found the solution to that problem which fixed the other issue:
https://community.grafana.com/t/solved-auth-google-login-failed-error-required-email-domain-not-fulfilled/19752

Answer (score 1):

The redirect uri must exactly match one of the ones you have registered in Google cloud console for your app.

If it says you need `http://grafana.acme-live.co.uk:3000/login/google` then just add that

Currently you only have `https://grafana.acme.co.uk:3000/login/google` added which is not going to match exactly as your sending http but you have https registered.

So either add the correct redirect uri or set your app to run https.

```
[server]
# Protocol (http or https)
protocol = https
```

## what is a redirect uri?

The redirect uri is the location your application has told google it is accepting the authorization response on.   Your application must be listing on that exact location and that location must be registered in google developer console.

Comment: sorry it's a typo on my part. Assume ttp://grafana.acme-live.co.uk:3000/login/google for both URLs. I will edit my post.

Comment: Also, if I use protocol=https then grafana will ask for cert files, but SSL is not enabled on the server, because SSL is managed at the ALB level. Is there any way I can force grafana to use the ALB's SSL ?

Comment: I cant help with grafana really I can only help you with the Google Oauth part of your issue., You could also just update your redirect uri and remove the https.